# Type-safe select and mapping of untyped raw result in Slick

Tags: sql, scala, slick, hlist

I have a situation when client application is not completely aware of database schema. For instance, I know for sure that there is an `email` field. But as a query result I would like to return all of the fields. They are not processed in any way, I will just serialize result as JSON. However, I would like to have type-safety for table selection and joining. Is it possible to do this in Slick (or maybe in other library)?

For instance, I have a table `users` with known schema of:

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String)](tag, "users") {
  def email = column[String]("email")
  def * = (email) // Not sure about this. Should it be rewritten?
}
```

Is it possible to query this table (or join with other tables) in a type-safe way like this:

```
emailDB.run(TableQuery[Users].filter(_.email === encryptedEmail).result)
```

but somehow get all of the record's fields and map a result set of all of the fields from a table as `Map[String, String]` or  `Map[String, Any]` or Shapeless' HList?

P.S. I have a relatively crazy idea to replace wildcard `*` with a function, that lazily checks table schema and produces a heterogeneous list to map into